# Animate custom presentation of ViewController in OS X Yosemite

Tags: objective-c, macos, osx-yosemite

I want to implement new method, I searched a lot on Google and Stack Overflow but I have not found an example.

```
- (void)presentViewController:(NSViewController *)viewController animator:(id <NSViewControllerPresentationAnimator>)animator
```

this method is available in OSX 10.10 and this method need to implement the protocol `NSViewControllerPresentationAnimator` which has these two methods

```
- (void)animatePresentationOfViewController:(NSViewController *)viewController fromViewController:(NSViewController *)fromViewController 

- (void)animateDismissalOfViewController:(NSViewController *)viewController fromViewController:(NSViewController *)fromViewController
```

These methods allow us to do custom animation between two NSViewController's
I need an example of implementation, I have this code:

```
- (IBAction)openTask:(id)sender {
    
    NSStoryboard *storyboard = [NSStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    Tasks *task = [storyboard instantiateControllerWithIdentifier:@"tasks"];
    [self presentViewController:task animator:self];
 
}

- (void)animatePresentationOfViewController:(NSViewController *)viewController
                         fromViewController:(NSViewController *)fromViewController
{
    
    
}

- (void)animateDismissalOfViewController:(NSViewController *)viewController
                      fromViewController:(NSViewController *)fromViewController
{
    
    
}
```

Can anyone help me with an example of how I could have implemented this transition?

Comment: Is there more help you need or is my example enough?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here is a simple version (Swift) that fades in the new viewcontroller's view.
I am sure you can translate that into Objective-C.

You will want to actually use Autolayout instead of just changing the frame, but that would have made the example a bit longer (not too difficult. Just add constraints after you add the view)

I am not sure if you need viewcontroller containment as well. Then there would need to be the appropriate calls to *addChildViewController* and so on. Maybe someone can shed some light on when this might be necessary or if it is actually good practice in any case.

```
class MyTransitionAnimator: NSObject, NSViewControllerPresentationAnimator {

    func animatePresentationOfViewController(viewController: NSViewController, fromViewController: NSViewController) {

        let bottomVC = fromViewController
        let topVC = viewController

        // make sure the view has a CA layer for smooth animation
        topVC.view.wantsLayer = true

        // set redraw policy
        topVC.view.layerContentsRedrawPolicy = .OnSetNeedsDisplay

        // start out invisible
        topVC.view.alphaValue = 0

        // add view of presented viewcontroller
        bottomVC.view.addSubview(topVC.view)

        // adjust size
        topVC.view.frame = bottomVC.view.frame

        // Do some CoreAnimation stuff to present view
        NSAnimationContext.runAnimationGroup({ (context) -> Void in

            // fade duration
            context.duration = 2
            // animate to alpha 1
            topVC.view.animator().alphaValue = 1

        }, completionHandler: nil)

    }

    func animateDismissalOfViewController(viewController: NSViewController, fromViewController: NSViewController) {

        let bottomVC = fromViewController
        let topVC = viewController

        // make sure the view has a CA layer for smooth animation
        topVC.view.wantsLayer = true

        // set redraw policy
        topVC.view.layerContentsRedrawPolicy = .OnSetNeedsDisplay

        // Do some CoreAnimation stuff to present view
        NSAnimationContext.runAnimationGroup({ (context) -> Void in

            // fade duration
            context.duration = 2
            // animate view to alpha 0
            topVC.view.animator().alphaValue = 0

        }, completionHandler: {

            // remove view
            topVC.view.removeFromSuperview()
        })

    }
}
```

Hope this gets you started!

Comment: Oh, and be sure to read http://jwilling.com/osx-animations before changing the frame using Core Animation. It's an excellent article!